# How to run batch file via task scheduler to route print and keep the DOS window open/command line available to add text

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-7-x64

in advance, thank you for any insight you may be able to offer. i know that there is a very similar post to my scenario and i have tried all variations of the answer but cannot get it to work for me as per the initial or edited instructions. in order to circumvent the uac nags, i am running windows 7 (64 bit) and trying to run a batch file to simply 'route print cmd /k' via task scheduler and desktop shortcut but i want the DOS window to remain open and allow me to continue typing into it. when i execute the actual file, it runs as desired, however when it runs via task scheduler, the dos window closes immediately. to no avail, i have tried multiple things such as changing the 'program/script' field from C:\location\batchfilename.bat to just cmd and inputting the various arguments including cmd /k or /k or /k C:\location\batchfilename.bat to the task's 'add arguments' field and/or the batch script itself. although i do not want pause as it would close the window after pressing any key, i have also tried it in the script itself and the arguments field but it too does not keep the dos window open when running as scheduled task. nothing seems to work - your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you talk in one long burst like that, without pausing for breath? :-) Please [edit] your question to include the source code for your batch file and the actual command you're using to run it via Task Scheduler, as well as adding some paragraph breaks (Enter works fine for adding them) so that we can make some sense. A huge wall of text is extremely difficult to read.

Comment: `route print cmd /k` isn't a valid command...